# How to distinguish buildings from vegetation in LIDAR data?

Tags: lidar, ecognition

In order to extract the vegetation mask in [ecognition](http://www.ecognition.com/), with object base analysis, with creation of the rule sets, the buildings were also classified! Any idea how to extract building from vegetation? I tried to use shape and also asymmetry, but other ideas are most welcome.

Comment: what software are you using and what is the format of your processed lidar data?

Answer (score 5):

There are several online videos showing how to use Image Analysis with Lidar data with eCognition.

Image Classification methods are key to extracting the correct data.

http://www.ecognition.com/support/media-library/videos/

Vegetation (Tree Canopy Extraction)
http://www.ecognition.com/support/media-library/videos/ecognition-image-analysis-extracting-tree-canopy-lidar

Building Extraction
http://www.ecognition.com/support/media-library/videos/obia-lidar-technical-demo-pt24

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution in [LAStools](http://lastools.org) called lasclassify.exe ([README](http://lastools.org/download/lasclassify_README.txt)) that you could try. The full version (up to a certain point limit) is available on-line for research and evaluation purposes.

Comment: We appreciate replies from vendors and other commercially interested parties, Martin, but in such cases to retain credibility it's crucial that you identify your connection with the solution you are recommending.

Comment: @whuber Martin Isenburg is the developer of LAStools.  He is one of (if not the) authority on filtering Lidar data. His algorithms form the basis for many commercial LIDAR software.  I wouldn't consider him a vendor, as "his" software is opensource for most uses and is a generous gift to the Lidar community.

Comment: LAStools is no longer opensource and Martin would, in this case, be considered a vendor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArcGIS, you could try the LP360 for ArcGIS: Classify tool.

http://www.qcoherent.com/products/classify.html

Free trial

Answer (score 1):

Each Lidar point should have multiple "returns" - the last return is likely to be either building or ground level. Previous ones are likely to be hits on vegetation such as a tree canopy. So my sense is that you could discard all but the last return as being vegetation. That might help.

Comment: @Andre Silva, in the case of high density vegetation, one can use "Number of returns" parameter but not last return. The vegetation have more number of returns compared to buildings.