# 3D model of rooftops based on LiDAR and cadastral data?

Tags: dem, 3d, lidar, modelling, 3d-model

I´m trying to model building rooftops based on a LiDAR dataset. I've already interpolated using Delaunay's triangulation a DEM with 1 meter resolution. Due to LiDAR data is not accurate in building edges, I managed to get cadastre data so I have building boundaries.

Does anyone know how to build a 3D model of rooftops based on the previously mentioned inputs (DEM and cadastre data).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a specific question? It's hard to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: Near duplicate, but ArcGIS specific: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/how-to-make-3d-building-models-from-lidar-data

Answer (score 2):

Use the aerial imagery to get the horizontal building dimensions, width and length. Use the LIDAR for vertical measurements to know what the heights are.

If you want an automated method you're probably not going to find it in free software.

Comment: The asker does not say that aerial imagery is available nor does he say that he is looking for free software to do this.

Comment: I'm supposed to believe he has lidar data but not access to google earth?